# Building a Application with ChatGPT API: Managing Conversations for Multiple Users

Tags: node.js, openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

I'm developing a application that utilizes the ChatGPT chat completion API to facilitate conversations between users and an AI. The application should allow multiple users to interact simultaneously, with each conversation being maintained separately

I'm wondering how to efficiently manage conversations for multiple users in this setup:

1. Does the ChatGPT API provide any built-in mechanism to maintain conversation state or context?
2. If not, how should I handle session management and context tracking in my application to ensure   that each user's conversation is maintained separately?
3. Are there any best practices or recommended strategies for scaling the application to handle a large number of concurrent users?

I'm using Node.js for the backend of my application. Any insights, suggestions, or resources would be greatly appreciated!

In my Node.js application using Express.js I am exploring libraries of OpenAI . However, I'm unsure about how to scale this setup to handle a large number of concurrent users efficiently.

I was expecting to find a solution or best practice for managing conversations for multiple users in a chat application powered by the ChatGPT API. Ideally, I'm looking for guidance on how to maintain conversation state, handle session management, and scale the application effectively to support a growing user base.